# Erro ao utilizar Long.parseLong para capturar valor de um EditText para uma variável do tipo LONG

Tags: android, android-studio, edittext, textview

Criei um app que contém somente uma activity. Nessa activity existem 3 **EditTexts** e 1 **TextView**.

Criei 3 variáveis do tipo **long** (`l01, l02 e l03`) para receberem o valor dos 3 **EditTexts**.

**MainActivity:**

```js
package genesysgeneration.treerule;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText et01, et02, et03;
    private TextView tv01;
    private long l01, l02, l03;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        l01=0;
        l02=0;
        l03=0;

        et01=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et01);
        et02=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et02);
        et03=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et03);

        l01=Long.parseLong(et01.getText().toString());
        l02=Long.parseLong(et02.getText().toString());
        l03=Long.parseLong(et03.getText().toString());

        tv01=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv01);
        tv01.setText(String.valueOf(l01*l02*l03));

    }
}
```

Como podem ver no código utilizei o método **parseLong**, porém o mesmo não fez o app funcionar e o aplicativo nem abre.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**No android monitor dá isso:**

```js
01-30 20:41:31.441 2448-2448/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{genesysgeneration.treerule/genesysgeneration.treerule.MainMenuActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""
                                                     at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:125)
                                                     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:346)
                                                     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:319)
                                                     at genesysgeneration.treerule.MainMenuActivity.onCreate(MainMenuActivity.java:27)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Tentei mudar as seguinte linhas com o ".trim" como vi em [Invalid long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042359/invalid-long-exception), porém o erro persistiu:

```js
l01=Long.parseLong(et01.getText().toString().trim());
l02=Long.parseLong(et02.getText().toString().trim());
l03=Long.parseLong(et03.getText().toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso opte por não usar um botão para resgatar o valores somente depois de clicado, podes usar o `addTextChangeListener()`. Desta forma, na media que adicionar o valor no EditText, ele já atribuirá ao `long`. Veja:

### EditText 1

```
et01.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

          l01=Long.parseLong(et01.getText().toString().trim());
          tv01.setText(String.valueOf(l01*l02*l03));

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

### EditText 2

```
et02.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

          l02=Long.parseLong(et02.getText().toString().trim());
          tv01.setText(String.valueOf(l01*l02*l03));

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

### EditText 3

```
et03.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

          l03=Long.parseLong(et03.getText().toString().trim());
          tv01.setText(String.valueOf(l01*l02*l03));

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Entretanto você pode adicionar um botão e resgatar os valores no momento em que clicar nele. Desta forma:

```
meuBotao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        l01=Long.parseLong(et01.getText().toString().trim());
        l02=Long.parseLong(et02.getText().toString().trim());
        l03=Long.parseLong(et03.getText().toString().trim());

        tv01.setText(String.valueOf(l01*l02*l03));
    }
});
```